# Why Program.cs can't find my custom method CreateDbIfNotExists?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm following this Microsoft tutorial about .NET Core 6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/persist-data-ef-core/4-interacting-data

In Program.cs I'm calling my custom method 'CreateDbIfNotExists'

This is my Program.cs

```
using ContosoPizza.Services;
// Additional using declarations
using ContosoPizza.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Add the PizzaContext
builder.Services.AddSqlite<PizzaContext>("Data Source=ContosoPizza.db");

// Add the PromotionsContext

builder.Services.AddScoped<PizzaService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

// Add the CreateDbIfNotExists method call
app.CreateDbIfNotExists();

app.Run();
```

and this is my namespace ContosoPizza.Data

```
namespace ContosoPizza.Data;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void CreateDbIfNotExists(this IHost host)
    {
        {
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<PizzaContext>();
                if (context.Database.EnsureCreated())
                {
                    DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I tried to build it, I received the following error message

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/01MyProjects/ContosoPizza/mslearn-persist-data-ef-core/ContosoPizza/Program.cs",
    "owner": "csharp",
    "code": "CS1061",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "'WebApplication' does not contain a definition for 'CreateDbIfNotExists' and no accessible extension method 'CreateDbIfNotExists' accepting a first argument of type 'WebApplication' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [ContosoPizza]",
    "source": "csharp",
    "startLineNumber": 34,
    "startColumn": 5,
    "endLineNumber": 34,
    "endColumn": 24
}]
```

here is my files structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPZub.png)

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you write `ContosoPizza.Data.Extensions.CreateDbIfNotExists(app);`? (If that fails to compile as well, it at least takes the extension method aspect out of the picture...)

Comment: [{
 "resource": "/c:/01MyProjects/ContosoPizza/mslearn-persist-data-ef-core/ContosoPizza/Program.cs",
 "owner": "csharp",
 "code": "CS0234",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'ContosoPizza.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [ContosoPizza]",
 "source": "csharp",
 "startLineNumber": 35,
 "startColumn": 1,
 "endLineNumber": 35,
 "endColumn": 29
}]

Comment: It's a different error code

Comment: Okay, well that sounds like your `Extensions` class isn't being compiled for whatever reason. How are you building this code? What does the file structure look like?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm very new in all this. How could I know if the Extensions class has been compiled (or not)?

Comment: Well one way would be to put a deliberate error in there - complete garbage. See whether you get an error. But again, how are you building this code, and what does the file structure look like?

Comment: I put at the beginning a link to the Microsoft tutorial i'm following. It was working until the last part of step 4.  Please, tell me exactly what you need to see. Do you prefer continue in the chat? Thanks.

Comment: Your `Extensions` file should be `Extensions.cs`. Likewise `DbInitializer` should be `DbInitializer.cs`. Those files aren't being included in the build due to having the wrong extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! that was the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet What led you to believe that his C# files had a missing extension?

Comment: @silkfire: The screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and same error message.

Because I forgot to **SAVE** the `Extensions.cs` file.

Comment: The problem was solved in January, and for an entirely different reason. When your suggestion is a guess like this, it would be far better to put it as a comment than as an answer - and read the other comments first!

Comment: I should indeed take a good look at the comments, you're right. Not saving that file would have reported the same error though. I think I should revise my answer, because it might also help someone as careless as me. Anyway, my initial intentions were good, but thanks for the correction.